# Jquery datepicker.js not allowing minDate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm using the datepicker plugin in my rails app and I can't get the minDate configuration to work.

```
<%= text_field_tag 'milestone_override', nil, size: 10, readonly: "readonly", id: 'milestone-override-datepicker' %>

$("#milestone-override-datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: '-5',
        maxDate: "+1M +10D"
      });
```

Comment: Which exact datepicker plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Error:

My app was using bootstrap datepicker, which looks the same.

jquery ui would use minDate
bootstrap would use startDate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI datepicker, then you need to specify a number (not a string) as offset from today or add `D` to your string:

```
$("#milestone-override-datepicker").datepicker({
    // Option 1:
    minDate: '-5D',

    // Option 2:
    minDate: -5,

    maxDate: "+1M +10D"
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I tried that too. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are you using jQ UI datepicker? If yes, then look into your js console and see if there are any errors there?

Comment: yep and no errors. I have changed the id name to see if it's being configured by another instance of datepicker... nothing

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: trying. external resources don't seem to be working on jsfiddle